# Font Awesome: Not rendering in IE on S3

Tags: css, internet-explorer, amazon-s3, fonts, font-awesome

I have read through other posts on Stack regarding Font Awesome icons not rendering in IE & Firefox.  One post helped fix the Firefox issue by adding a CORS block of code to the URL's S3 Bucket, yet still IE will not render these icons.

Per the screenshot this is what I am seeing in IE when I inspect the element.  IE is crossing out the css code (content:"\ff09").

[image]

I am running everything from the S3 bucket... the font awesome css ... font awesome's fonts and yet still the font icons do not render in IE.  I am not utilizing any CDN for this.

Might anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: where's the rule that's actually getting applied? (your image only shows that there's an override *somwhere*) Also, what does your CSS look like, and are there any not-200 codes for the font resource? (404, 403, 500, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

IT Departments can lock out "Font Download" from the different internet zones in IE.  If locked down tight you will not be able to change this setting.
Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Click Internet Icon and then Custom Level.  Find Downloads and Font download will be set to "Disable" probably.  You may request this change or site be added to "Trusted Sites".  "Trusted Sites" usually have that set to "Enable"

Answer (score 0):

For a week or two I have tried tons of different solutions to get IE and Firefox (changing CORS, editing .htaccess & more) to render both Font Awesome and Google Web Fonts.  I have had NO success and have spun my wheels over and over!

It turns out it's most likely the security settings/certificates or lack there of on my locked down work computer causing this problem.  NO matter how many things I try to do these fonts will never load on this computer(in IE & FF) due to the security settings IT has set on my workstation.